# Laravel Controller's constructor doesn't run

Tags: php, laravel, constructor

I have a Laravel web app, in which I have a "parent" controller for each of my other controllers. I built the logic this way because the database was powered by an online SOAP service.

My parent controller's constructor looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;
use SoapClient;
use Session;

class SoapCtrl extends Controller
{
    public $client;
    public function __construct(Request $request) {
        // SoapClient
        $wsdl = '******';
        $args = [
            'trace' => true,
            'exceptions' => true,
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        ];
        $this->client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $args);
    }
}
```

And I have a lot of other controllers extending this SoapCtrl, for example this one:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;
use SoapClient;
use Session;

class MagistralCtrl extends SoapCtrl {

    public function __construct(Request $request) {
        parent::__construct($request);
        if(!parent::loggedin()) {
            return '';
        }
        if(!parent::have_right('magisztralis')) {
            return view('nopermission', $this->args);
        }
    }
}
```

They can all use `$this->client->anySoapMethod` in functions for the views, so it looks like `client` was inherited and works. But the `__construct` function don't run. I tried it with `die('hello')`, still, nothing happened. My constructor in the extension controller just doesn't work.

Please help, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: where did you try `die()`??

Comment: In my second controllers constructor, like this: `public function __construct(Request $request) { die('hello'); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to shivanshu I found the solution. By default, Laravel use the `Controller` class for controllers, and in normal cases you always extend this one with yours.

However, if you want to extend another controller, you still need this one as well to get your constructors (and maybe other things) executed properly. I need to always `use` this default controller in every other.

So the solution is simple, put `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` to the top of your files:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;
use SoapClient;
use Session;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; // You need to add this line to get it work

class MagistralCtrl extends SoapCtrl {

    public function __construct(Request $request) {
        parent::__construct($request);
        die('hello'); // Now prints hello
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try repository pattern approach

Answer (score 0):

Thing is in Laravel controller constructor executes before any middleware, so there is no user yet.

another thing is extending controller is bad practice, you are creating God's object. In my opinion you should create a service for SOAP requests instead of adding in to the parent controller and extending it.

```
<?php

class SoapCtrl
{
    /**
     * @var SoapClient
     */
    private $client;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $wsdl = '******';
        $args = [
            'trace' => true,
            'exceptions' => true,
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        ];
        $this->client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $args);
    }

    /**
     * @return SoapClient
     */
    public function getClient()
    {
        return $this->client;
    }
}



class MagistralCtrl extends Controller
{
    public function myMethod(SoapCtrl $soapCtrl)
    {
        $soapClient = $soapCtrl->getClient();

    }
}
```

Comment: `controller constructor executes before any middleware` To me it seems like it doesn't get executed at all.

Comment: try to put die inside parent constructor

Comment: Parent constructor works, but I want to know why the exntension doesn't, and how to fix it without rewriting the whole thing.

Comment: Nope, it seems like my constructor is simply skipped. Any other method in my controller works as expected.

Comment: that's strange which laravel version you are using ?

Comment: I'm using version 5.4.35

Comment: But if I get you correctly - and searching on the web also point me to this direction - I need to modify the built-in `Controller` class to act like my `SoapCtrl`, and I need to extend this one?

Comment: well other thing you can do it is put your soap client methods/logic in to a separate service class something like SoapRequestService and inject in to the controller method directly as parameter. which will allow you to test your service and controller method in isolation.

Comment: one more this is your controller constructor working without extending soap controller so if you extend default laravel controller ? also remove the check for the loggedin. just do echo 'a';exit;

Comment: Yes, it gets executed this way, but of course throwing a lot of errors. Maybe I can `extend Controller` and just `use SoapCtrl` somehow?

Comment: Yes Thats the right way of doing it so don't extend SoapCtrl move all logic to separate class and also make sure SoapCtrl is not extending laravel's default controller and inject it to the __construct through DI.

Comment: Found a relatively easy solution (no need for refractor the whole code), thanks for your guidance as well. Put it to the answers so maybe I can help future readers with this simple approach.

Comment: Your answer is good, the problem with that is I have a lot of code built this way, so it will took hours (or maybe days) to make such a big modification to all of my files. By the way thanks for your effort, you helped me a lot.